# How to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to a variable

Tags: perl, system, stdout, stderr, redirect

I want to redirect `STDERR` and `STDOUT` to a variable. I did this.

```
close(STDOUT);
close(STDERR);

my $out;
open(STDOUT, ">>", \$out);
open(STDERR, ">>", \$out);

for(1..10)
{
    print "print\n"; # this is ok. 
    warn "warn\n"; # same
    system("make"); # this is lost. neither in screen nor in variable.
}
```

The problem with `system`. I want the output of this call to be captured too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you seeking to capture the output in a variable?  If so, you have use backticks or `qx{}` with appropriate redirection.  For example, you could use:

```
#/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Ensure we have a way to write messages
open my $fh, '>', "output" or die;

close(STDOUT);
close(STDERR);

my $out;
open(STDOUT, ">>", \$out) or do { print $fh, "failed to open STDOUT ($!)\n"; die };
open(STDERR, ">>", \$out) or do { print $fh, "failed to open STDERR ($!)\n"; die };

foreach my $i (1..10)
{
    print "print $i\n"; 
    warn "warn $i\n";
    my $extra = qx{make pth$i 2>&1};
    print $fh "<<$i>><<$out>><<$extra>>\n";
}
```

(I happen to have programs pth1, pth2 and pth3 in the directory - they were made OK; pth4 and above write errors to stderr; the redirection was necessary.)

You should always check the success of operations such as `open()`.

Why is this necessary?  Because writing to a variable requires the cooperation of the process doing the writing - and `make` doesn't know how to cooperate.

Comment: The problem with `qx` is that you can only capture one (STDOUT) output stream. If you want STDERR separately, you cannot redirect STDERR to STDOUT.

Answer (score 13):

use [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture::Tiny)!

Comment: This answer could explain how to do it with core Perl, and then, maybe, refer to a package that exists to help replicating code. Just throwing in a name of a package is a bit poor kind of solution IMHO, even if it works.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to [redirect and restore STDOUT](https://www.perl.com/article/45/2013/10/27/How-to-redirect-and-restore-STDOUT/). Some of them work with STDERR too.  Here are my two favorites:

Using `select`:

```
my $out;
open my $fh, ">>", \$out;
select $fh;
print "written to the variable\n";
select STDOUT;
print "written to original STDOUT\n";
```

Using `local`:

```
my $out;
do {
    local *STDOUT;
    open STDOUT, ">>", \$out;
    print "written to the variable\n";
};
print "written to original STDOUT\n";
```

Enjoy.

Comment: It seems this answer misses the fact that redirection to a variable seems to fail for external processes being run.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `use IPC::Open3`?

Comment: That wouldn't work for the current process, only a newly opened process.

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR Answer

**[`use Capture::Tiny;`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny)**

### Merged STDOUT and STDERR

If you want `STDOUT` (from `print()`s) and `STDERR` (from `warn()`s) to be merged, then use...

```
my ($merged,  @result) = capture_merged { print "Hello, world!" };  # static code
my ($merged,  @result) = capture_merged { eval $codetoeval };       # code in variable
```

### Separated STDOUT and STDERR

If you want them separated...

```
my ($stdout, $stderr, @result) = capture { print "Hello, world!" };   # static code
my ($stdout, $stderr, @result) = capture { eval $codetoeval };        # code in variable
```

### Results of Eval

`@result` indicates the success, with success being `[1]`, and failure being `[]`.  Tiny has a ton of other functions that you can look through for other cases, like code references, etc..  But I think the code above should cover most of any Perl developer's needs.

Comment: It's after https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415743/6607497, but you explained some details, so I upvoted the answer.