# print truth table in to odt file

Tags: perl, openoffice-writer, odt

i want to print truth table in to a table in an adt file, t got a program but i don know how to get vale or value to print to odt file, this program just print result on screen !

```
sub truth_table {
    my $s = shift;
    #print "$s\n";
    my  @vars;
    for ($s =~ /([a-zA-Z_]\w*)/g) {
        push @vars, $_ ;

    }
    #print "$s\n";
    #print "$_\n";
    #print Dumper \@vars;
    #print "\n", join("\t", @vars, $s), "\n", '-' x 40, "\n";
    #print Dumper \@vars;
    @vars = map("\$$_", @vars);
    $s =~ s/([a-zA-Z_]\w*)/\$$1/g;
    $s = "print(".join(',"\t",', map("($_?'1':'0')", @vars, $s)).",\"\\n\")";
    $s = "for my $_ (0, 1) { $s }" for (reverse @vars);
    eval $s;
}
truth_table 'A ^ A_1';
```

Comment: [this](http://search.cpan.org/dist/OpenOffice-OODoc/OODoc.pod) should help you

Comment: i know that link , but the problem is how to take the value of A and A_1 and the result to an @array or %hash to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the result of `eval` with [Capture::Tiny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415743/5100564), then split the string into a two-dimensional array based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4226073/5100564.

```
use Capture::Tiny 'capture_stdout';

sub truth_table {
    #...the rest of your code here...
    my $stdout = capture_stdout {
        eval $s;
    };
    return $stdout;
}
$truth_string = truth_table 'A ^ A_1';
my @truth_array;
foreach my $line (split "\n", $truth_string) {
    push @truth_array, [split ' ', $line];
}
foreach my $line (@truth_array) {
    foreach my $val (@$line) {
        print $val;
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

For this to work, I executed the following commands based on [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

```
cpan
install Capture::Tiny
```

However, I would solve this problem in LibreOffice with a Python macro instead.  [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python) makes it convenient to enter and run this code.

```
import uno
from itertools import product

def truth_table():
    NUM_VARS = 2  # A and B
    columns = NUM_VARS + 1
    rows = pow(2, NUM_VARS) + 1
    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oText = oDoc.getText()
    oCursor = oText.createTextCursorByRange(oText.getStart())
    oTable = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.TextTable")
    oTable.initialize(rows, columns)
    oText.insertTextContent(oCursor, oTable, False)
    for column, heading in enumerate(("A", "B", "A ^ B")):
        oTable.getCellByPosition(column, 0).setString(heading)
    row = 1  # the second row
    for p in product((0, 1), repeat=NUM_VARS):
        result = truth_function(*p)
        for column in range(NUM_VARS):
            oTable.getCellByPosition(column, row).setString(p[column])
        oTable.getCellByPosition(column + 1, row).setString(result)
        row += 1

def truth_function(x, y):
    return pow(x, y);

g_exportedScripts = truth_table,
```

[image]

Using `product` in this way is based on [Creating a truth table for any expression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548744/creating-a-truth-table-for-any-expression-in-python).

More documentation for Python-UNO can be found at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python.

Comment: $s = "print(".join(',"\t", ', map("($_?'1':'0')", @vars, $s)).",\"\\n\")";
 how to get join with out print, every time i make truth table it print on the sceen again , but i dont need result on screen